# External Hard Disk is Not detected by ubuntu 16.04

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive, external-hdd

I'm on a fresh install of ubuntu 16.04 (dual boot with windows 10) and have noticed that my external hard drive (seagate backup plus 2TB) is not detected at all.There are two partitions on this disk (exfat and NFTS) which both work fine on windows and the drive appear in my bios. Hence I can safely say that it is in perfect working order

It doesn't appear in ubuntu's disk utility nor does it appear when using lsusb or fdisk commands via terminal so I'm pretty sure that it isn't a matter of needing to manually mount it (which seems to be a common issue with the exfat systems, and I have already tried installing the packages for exfat).

Any ideas? please help

Edit: the device/drive does not appear in gparted or disks (utility)

Comment: U can't mount it untill it become visible in system. Try another USB port and run `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: I've attempted that via multiple usb ports and it still isn't detected. Plus ive tried other USB storage devices and they seem to work fine

Comment: Try to boot from bootable usb like winPE or Ubuntu installer. Maybe it's hardware problem